What's the difference between depth and shallow options when cloning with Git plugin in Jenkins
I've read a lot of posts and articles in the Internet (even the Git official doc) but I still do not understand the difference between  using depth: n and shallow: true. The official documentation (https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) do not even show the depth: n option. After trying different combinations I do not understand what is the difference between them.

shallow=true tells the plugin to only check out a shallow copy (without the full history). Once it's enabled, you can also set the depth option to define how many commits of history you want to get when performing a shallow clone.

I.e., one cannot set depth: n without first setting shallow=true?

@phd AFAIK, that's correct

@Mureinik when you say that with shallow: true the full history is not downloaded you mean that no history is downloaded or some history but not full?

@Felipe the depth parameter determines the "size" of the history, in terms of number of commits going back from the HEAD.

@Mureinik in this case I'm asking about shallow: true, not depth

@Felipe IWBN to experiment. I expect the default depth to be 1 immediately after setting shallow=true.
